# How can I prevent line breaks between words and punctuation in CSS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have some text in a paragraph.
My problem is that when punctuation is at the end of a word, it can sometimes be wrapped to the next line.
Like this:

```
This is the text
, This is a new line
```

Can I resolve this with CSS or jQuery?

Comment: Can you post a JSfiddle of your situation? We can then test the outcome based on that what you see.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this issue in Chrome (which treats the comma as part of the word). Which browser are you using?

Comment: Could try `<span style="white-space: no-wrap;">text,</span>` Though I've never encountered this problem, unless you're putting a space between the end of the word and the comma?

Comment: First you could do some `replace(' ,',',',text);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't put a space between the word and the punctuation, and that it is wrapped anyway, you can use the `white-space: nowrap;` [css instruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space). Otherwise, if you need a space between the word and the punctuation, like before a `?`, use the non-breaking space code. You can have it by typing `alt + 0160` on your keyboard if you're using Windows. For more keyboard methods, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods).

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `space` before the punctuation by a `non breaking space`:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| System/application      | Entry method                               |
|-------------------------|--------------------------------------------|
| macOS                   | ⌥+Space                                    |
| Microsoft Windows       | Alt+0160 or Alt+255 (does not always work) |
| Linux or Unix using X11 | Compose, Space, Space or AltGr+Space       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Completing this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15637588/1310605

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your problem rise because of some space symbol located before comma, like `... text , This ...` when it should be `... text, This ....`

At least that is the only reason I can see. If you will take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SxYbJ/1/) fiddle, you will find that text in third `<p>` is never wrapped like you mentioned. (you may need to choose different width for your browser. Example above works in Chrome, but for Firefox widths are little different)

So, simply ensure that you have no spaces between text and comma.