# HTML: Prevent line breaks before some punctuation characters preceeded by a whitespace

Tags: javascript, typography, punctuation

In French typography conventions, few punctuation characters like `;`,`:` or `?` must be preceeded by a white space. This is causing unwanted line breaks when the punction is at the border of its HTML container.

```
Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir ? Non, merci.
```

becomes

```
Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir 
? Non, merci.
```

The objective is to get it like this:

```
Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce 
soir ? Oui, bien sûr.
```

I didn't find any way to avoid line breaks before those characters using CSS. Moreover:

- Manually adding `&nbsp;` before every occurence is not an option due to existing data and ergonomy constraints.
- Using CSS `whitespace: nowrap;` is not an option because it must happen in all other cases.

I'm considering using a global javascript function running a `str.replace(" ?", "&nbsp;?");` but I can't figure out few things:

- How and when triggering it
- How to select the appropriate tags
- How to replace innerText only (ie not properties content)

Any advice?

**Note:** [Whitespace before some punctuation characters in French: is there a CSS way to avoid lines breaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851807/whitespace-before-some-punctuation-characters-in-french-is-there-a-css-way-to-a) is sharing the same objective but has a pure CSS constraint that I don't have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you'd do the replacement of the space with a hard space **server-side**, rather than client-side, since if you do it client-side you'll have the problem that the content will reflow when you update it, which will cause a perceptible flash/movement.

Mostly, you'll have this issue within Text nodes, e.g.:

```
<p>Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir ? Non, merci.</p>
```

That's an Element (the `p` element) with a single Text node inside it.

It's *possible* to have it where the space is in one Text node and the punctuation in another:

```
<p><span>Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir </span>? Non, merci.</p>
```

There, "Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir" and the space are in one Text node (inside a `span`), but the punctuation is in another text node (in the `p`). I'm going to assume that's rare enough we don't need to worry about it.

To deal with it within Text nodes is relatively easy:

```
fixSpaces(document.body);

function fixSpaces(node) {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 1: // Element
            for (let child = node.firstChild;
                 child;
                 child = child.nextSibling) {
                fixSpaces(child);
            }
            break;

        case 3: // Text node
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/ ([;?!])/g, "\u00a0$1");
            break;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
// Obviously, you wouldn't have this in a `setTimeout` in your
// real code, you'd call it directly right away
// as shown in the answer
console.log("Before...");
setTimeout(() => {
    fixSpaces(document.body);
    console.log("After");
}, 1000);

function fixSpaces(node) {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 1: // Element
            for (let child = node.firstChild;
                 child;
                 child = child.nextSibling) {
                fixSpaces(child);
            }
            break;

        case 3: // Text node
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/ ([;?!])/g, "\u00a0$1");
            break;
    }
}
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 220px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<p>Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir ? Non, merci.</p>
```

You'd have this in a `script` tag at the end of the `body`, just before the closing `</body>` element.

**But again**: If you can do this server-side, that would be better, to avoid the reflow.

---

If we want to try to handle the case where one Text node ends with a space and the next starts with the punctuation, as I showed above:

```
<p><span>Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir </span>? Non, merci.</p>
```

...one approach is to get an array of all the Text nodes and then look to see if we have one ending with a space and the next starting with punctuation. This is imperfect because it doesn't try to handle the case where the Text node ending with a space is at the end of a block element (e.g., so the punctuation is always going to be on a different line visually), but it may be better than nothing. The only downside it you can end up with block elements with an extra hard space at the end.

```
fixSpaces(document.body);

function gatherText(node, array = []) {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 1: // Element
            for (let child = node.firstChild;
                 child;
                 child = child.nextSibling) {
                array = gatherText(child, array);
            }
            break;

        case 3: // Text node
            array.push(node);
            break;
    }
    return array;
}

function fixSpaces(node) {
    const texts = gatherText(node);
    for (let i = 0, len = texts.length; i < len; ++i) {
        const text = texts[i];
        const str = text.nodeValue = text.nodeValue.replace(/ ([;?|])/g, "\u00A0$1");
        if (i < len - 1 && str[str.length - 1] === " " && /^[;?!]/.test(texts[i + 1].nodeValue)) {
            // This node ends with a space and the next starts with punctuation,
            // replace the space with a hard space
            text.nodeValue = str.substring(0, str.length - 1) + "\u00A0";
        }
    }
}
```

```js
console.log("Before...");
setTimeout(() => {
    fixSpaces(document.body);
    console.log("After");
}, 1000);

function gatherText(node, array = []) {
    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 1: // Element
            for (let child = node.firstChild;
                 child;
                 child = child.nextSibling) {
                array = gatherText(child, array);
            }
            break;

        case 3: // Text node
            array.push(node);
            break;
    }
    return array;
}

function fixSpaces(node) {
    const texts = gatherText(node);
    for (let i = 0, len = texts.length; i < len; ++i) {
        const text = texts[i];
        const str = text.nodeValue = text.nodeValue.replace(/ ([;?|])/g, "\u00A0$1");
        if (i < len - 1 && str[str.length - 1] === " " && /^[;?!]/.test(texts[i + 1].nodeValue)) {
            // This node ends with a space and the next starts with punctuation,
            // replace the space with a hard space
            text.nodeValue = str.substring(0, str.length - 1) + "\u00A0";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 220px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Voulez-vous coucher avec moi ce soir </span>? Non, merci.</p>
```

---

Mapping your questions to the above:

> How and when triggering it

Putting it in a `script` element at the end of `body` triggers it very early, but after the content is in the DOM and thus ready for us to operate on it.

> How to select the appropriate tags

We ignore *tags* and work at the Text node level.

> How to replace innerText only (ie not properties content)

By working that the Text node level. Attributes aren't Text nodes so we don't process them.

Comment: Hi T.J., I can't change the data server-side as it's sent by an API I can't modify. I just tested your solution and it works great. I can't notice any visible flash / movement, probably because the occurences are rather rare in the page. Thank you very much.